# How do I make Selenium Python click on a button element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I just started using Selenium for Python and I am trying to click on a button element that is buried into a few div elements; I've tried so many things but nothing works. Everything in the code works besides the last part which is waiting for the button to be clickable and then clicking it. I would greatly appreciate some help here, thanks. :)

HTML:

[image: html code]

Code trials:

[image: my python code]

Error stacktrace:

[image: my python code error]

Comment: Please, consider inserting your code as text, not pictures, so that anyone could copy it to try.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/mindhashnl/roomsignage/blob/development/mysign_app/tests/frontend/admin/test_add_user.py. This is what we used

Comment: Never mind, I now see it's not your html and thus you cannot add name or id

Comment: But the find_element_by_XPath might still be viable (link in previous comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To click on `**Maybe Later**` button.
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following XPATH or CSS Selector.

**XPATH**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-footer']//button[@Class='btn btn-danger x' and text()='Maybe Later']"))).click()
```

**CSS Selector:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-danger.x[style='danger']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

css selectors will become your best friend,

you should always look to add as many attributes as possible

```
maybe_later_css = 'button[class="btn btn-danger"]'
# type str, '<tag-name>[<attribute-name> = <attribute-value>]'

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(maybe_later_css).click()
```

follow this format for all elements, its superior and works as expected every time

the only complication is when there exists multiple buttons with them same class name, in which case you should find a different attribute to fill the [] brackets

Answer (score 1):

The element with text as **Maybe Later** is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-footer#eFooter button.btn.btn-danger.x[style='danger']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-footer' and @id='eFooter']//button[@class='btn btn-danger x' and @style='danger']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```